# Conda Update Conda not working, neither is any type of install with Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install some packages with Conda but it fails every time for all that I have tried.  I tried the following statement and below is the message it returns.  I just need to know how to fix Conda to install some things that need to be installed with Conda.

`conda update conda`
This produces the following output:

```
Installing 'conda update conda' 
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - update
Current channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to
    https://anaconda.org
and use the search bar at the top of the page.
----- Failed to install 'conda update conda' -----
```

I also tried installing a specific version like so:

```
Installing 'conda install base defaults conda=23.5.1' 
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - base
  - install
  - defaults
Current channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to
    https://anaconda.org
and use the search bar at the top of the page.
Failed to install 'conda install base defaults conda=23.5.1
```

As an example I installed Pendulum with PIP and it worked fine.  I uninstalled it and tried to do a
`Conda Install Pendulum`
Which gave this:

```
Installing 'Conda Install Pendulum' -----
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - install
Current channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to
    https://anaconda.org
and use the search bar at the top of the page.
----- Failed to install 'Conda Install Pendulum' -----
```

I also tried removing Conda to re-install it but it would not let me remove it without another version replacing it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You wrote "I also tried removing Conda to re-install it but it would not let me remove it without another version replacing it." That doesn't make any sense to me. I use Anaconda on macOS and have never had any difficulty removing it when I've needed to start from a clean slate. How did you install it? Do you maybe have a corporate firewall that is interfering with the ability of the `conda` command to communicate with the Anaconda servers?

Comment: How are you running the commands. Your cmd seems to be misinterpreting them. What exactly are you writing in the cmd?

Comment: The message I get is below.  It is like it thinks I don't have Conda 23.5.2 but rather the previous version of conda 23.5.1: ```Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Solving environment: ...working... unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working... unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - conda==23.5.1```